# Postgres keep order of array

Tags: postgresql

I've got a simple array of IDs and need the query to reply with the same order

the query

```
SELECT id, title FROM pages WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY['6e3e4470', 'fec27534'])
```

the result

```
id          title
fec27534    2020
6e3e4470    2022
```

as you can see the array provides the "2022" ID first, but the response replies with it the last result
is there a way to keep this ordered by the array provided?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unnest(...) WITH ORDINALITY`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27287/2129) and an `INNER JOIN` to retain the array index:

```sql
SELECT pages.id, pages.title
FROM pages
INNER JOIN unnest(ARRAY['6e3e4470', 'fec27534'])
               WITH ORDINALITY tbl(id, idx) ON pages.id=tbl.id
ORDER BY tbl.idx
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you would not know whether all ids will be found, the ordering is probably not super useful, you should probably check it on the client against the input anyway.

You can however do it in Postgres as well:

```
SELECT ids.id, pages.title
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['6e3e4470', 'fec27534']) WITH ORDINALITY AS ids(id)
LEFT JOIN pages USING (id)
ORDER BY ordinality;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3o27iftb))</sup>

If you do want to get back only the found rows, use an inner `JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN`.